# Git, detect that local HEAD is pointing to a GIT tag

Tags: git

How can I detect if the actual working was checked based on a tag?

Let's say I'm performing the following GIT command:

```
 > git checkout 1.2.3
```

`git status` tells me that me my `HEAD` "pointer" is in a detached state. This could also be the case if I checkout SHA directly, e.g. via:

```
 > git checkout f1d96551ab404de047c846a0a59f76e8505046c9
```

How can I find out that `HEAD` is actually pointing to a commit, which has a tag on it?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

It lists the tags that are pointing at the `HEAD` commit.

If the tag `1.2.3` points at `f1d96551ab404de047c846a0a59f76e8505046c9` and you want to find out if the detached HEAD was caused by `git checkout 1.2.3` or `git checkout f1d96551ab404de047c846a0a59f76e8505046c9`, run `git reflog`.

Comment: Yes, this works too, and is fairly handier to use than my solution. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Whether your `HEAD` points directly (detached) to a tagged commit or to a branch whose tip is tagged,

```
git describe
```

would output the exact name of the tag ONLY IF it points to it directly, otherwise it will be suffixed by `-<numberOfCommitsSinceTag>-g<commitHash>`

But as a sidenote, `HEAD` can't point to a tag. It always point to a branch or a commit.

(Also, in case your repo tags are of the unannotated type, use the `--tags` flag for `describe`.)

Comment: NB: it only list *ONE* of the tags at HEAD, there may be others

Comment: @CervEd True. It wasn't specifically part of the initial question, though.

Answer (score 0):

List all tags which reference HEAD

```bash
git tag --points-at HEAD
```

Check if a specific tag (or one tag which matches pattern) is referenced by HEAD or another `<commit-ish>`

```bash
git describe --exact-match --match foo/tag-name-xyz
git describe --exact-match --match foo/tag-name-xyz HEAD~5
git describe --exact-match --match foo/tag-name-*
```

`git describe` will list *zero or one* tag, if there are multiple tags on a `<commit-ish>` that match, seems like it picks the first ASCII sorted